# Problem with installation of OpenVPN on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to install openVPN on Ubuntu, but I'm facing difficulties.

- I confirm that the system is up to date: `apt update && apt upgrade`
- Install the necessary packages: `apt install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg`
- I add the local repository for installation: `wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
- Run the following command: `echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list`

But this command gives me the following error: `bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list: Permission denied`

And when executing the command for installation: `apt install openvpn-as`
It gives me the following: `E: Unable to find package openvpn-as`

I'm trying to solve it, but I can't find solutions.
can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use sudo to edit files in /etc/apt. Try your last step again with sudo prepended to the command and enter your password when prompted.